# Using Alpine JS, enable dropdown when one or more checkboxes are checked

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a need to use some Alpine in an existing Livewire view.

We have rows of data, each with wire:model:defer assigned, each with a checkbox and I would like to use Alpine to enable a dropdown when one of these checkboxes are checked.

Currently I when I click one checkbox, all checkboxes are checked!

Below is a very dumbed down version of my view. I have an outer DIV 'x-data="{enableBulk: false}"' and my dropdown is in one child DIV and the rows, each with a checkbox are in another child DIV!

When I have the 'x-data="{enableBulk: false}"' on the parent DIV it works but ALL checkboxes are checked when I check just one!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.0/alpine.js"></script>
<div x-data="{ enableBulk: false }">

    <div class="">
        <div class="card-block mb-5">

            <div class="">
     
                <Select name="bulkAction" x-bind:disabled="!enableBulk"
                    wire:model="bulkAction" class="">
                    <option value=""> Bulk actions </option>
                    <option value="bulk_delete">Delete task(s) </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button wire:click='confirmBulkAction' class=" ">
                Apply
            </button>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div>


      <div class="table-bordered-row  group task-list " wire:key="row-11">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model:defer="checked" name="checked[]" x-model="enableBulk"
               id="task-checkbox-11" value="11" class="" />
        <div class="cursor-pointer unifirm-custom-row items-center">
          <a title="Row #1" class="" href="/xyz">
            Row #1
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="table-bordered-row  group task-list " wire:key="row-22">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model:defer="checked" name="checked[]" x-model="enableBulk"
               id="task-checkbox-22" value="22" class="" />
        <div class="cursor-pointer unifirm-custom-row items-center">
          <a title="Row #2" class="" href="/xyz">
            Row #2
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>


</div>
```

How can I ensure that the dropdown is enabled after just one of the checkboxes are checked, and without all checkboxes being checked when I check one of them?

Any help much appreciated; I know this is a little brief but it is last thing Friday :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array for the checkboxes so each of them has a unique state and check the length of this array to enable/disable the dropdown element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.0/alpine.js"></script>
<div x-data="{ enableBulk: [] }">
  <div class="">
    <div class="card-block mb-5">
        <div class="">     
            <select name="bulkAction" x-bind:disabled="enableBulk.length == 0"
                wire:model="bulkAction" class="">
                <option value=""> Bulk actions </option>
                <option value="bulk_delete">Delete task(s) </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button wire:click='confirmBulkAction' class=" ">
            Apply
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
  <div class="table-bordered-row  group task-list " wire:key="row-11">
    <input type="checkbox" wire:model.defer="checked" name="checked[]" x-model="enableBulk"
           id="task-checkbox-11" value="11" class="" />
    <div class="cursor-pointer unifirm-custom-row items-center">
      <a title="Row #1" class="" href="/xyz">
        Row #1
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table-bordered-row  group task-list " wire:key="row-22">
    <input type="checkbox" wire:model.defer="checked" name="checked[]" x-model="enableBulk"
           id="task-checkbox-22" value="22" class="" />
    <div class="cursor-pointer unifirm-custom-row items-center">
      <a title="Row #2" class="" href="/xyz">
        Row #2
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have set each checkbox to defer when adding this in and I was expecting this to checked array to sync when I clicked the Apply button but it appears not too. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try it with a dot instead of a colon here: `wire:model.defer`? Is it working without `.defer`?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what it was, thank you again, much appreciated...

Comment: Great! I fixed it in my answer as well.